# Get result of Parse.Query to anothet output variable, table. JAVASCRIPT and PARSE.COM

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

My function takes a single object from the database parse.com . I need send result of query to another variable. This is my function:

```
function pobierzOcene(id){
  var ocena = new Ocena();
    var q = new Parse.Query(Parse.Object.extend("Ocena"));
    q.equalTo("objectId",id);
    q.first({
      success: function(result){
        ocena.przedmiot = result.get("ocenaPrzedmiot").id;
        ocena.data = result.createdAt;
        ocena.waga = result.get("ocenWaga");
        ocena.wartosc = result.get("ocenaWartosc");
        return ocena;
      },
      error: function(e){
        console.log(e.message());
        return e.message();
      }
    });
}
```

I'm using "return ocena;" to do this. And in another function I have:

```
var o = pobierzOcene(oceny[j].id);
```

Why variable o is empty?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because of the asynchronous nature of Parse query functions. Your function `pobierzOcene` reaches the end of its execution as it does not wait for your asynchronous query function `q.first` to finish. One way of doin it is to rewrite the function with Parse Promises:

```
function pobierzOcene(id){
    var q = new Parse.Query("Ocena");
    q.equalTo("objectId",id);
    return q.first(); // return a promise to wait on
}
```

Call the function like this:

```
pobierzOcene(oceny[j].id).then( function(result) {

   // process the results here instead

}, function(error) {
    console.log(error); // error
});
```

Comment: Thanks for information. I don't know about asynchronous nature od Parse functions, can You tell me, how works Parse Promise? How can i get data with parse.promise?

Comment: I gave you an example above. Read the Parse documents to learn more: https://www.parse.com/docs/js/guide#promises

Comment: Tell me only, point to point, how works above function. In my know:
1. Start function pobierzOcene,
2. Do query, find object, and return q.first(), at the same time function pobierzOcene are waiting on result
3. Result is sending to function after ".then" and im working on this data.

Do i know understand?

Comment: You call the `pobierzOcene` and it returns immediately with an unresolved Promise but the `then` clause will be executed only when the query returns with the results, similar to how a callback function works

Answer (score 0):

I have a second problem with function .than i think..
Function takes a list of students and theirs attributes (name, surname, id  and degrees). In base: 
Student 0 has 3 degrees.
Student 1 hasn't degrees.
Student 2 has 4 degrees.

My function:

```
function DownloadList(){
  var query = new Parse.Query(Parse.Object.extend("Groups"));
  var Students;
  var degree = new Degree();

  query.equalTo("objectId",GroupId);
  query.include("listStudents");
  query.include("degree");
  query.include("StudentDegrees");
  query.include("SubjectDegree");
  query.first({
    success:function(res){
      var degree = res.get("Degree").id;
      var listOfStudents = res.get("listStudents");
      Students = new Array();

      for (var i=0; i<listOfStudents.length ; i++){
        student = new Student();
        student.name = listOfStudents[i].get("name");
        student.surname = listOfStudents[i].get("surname");
        student.index = listOfStudents[i].get("index");
        student.objectId = listOfStudents[i].id;

        var degrees = listOfStudents[i].get("StudentDegrees");
        for (var j in degrees){
          takeADegree(degrees[j].id).then(function(result){
            var degree = new Degree();
            degree.subject = result.get("SubjectDegree");
            if (subject == degree.subject.id){
              degree.date = result.createdAt;
              degree.weight = result.get("degreeWeight");
              degree.value = result.get("degreeValue");
              student.AddDegree(degree);
            }
          },
          function(error){
            console.log(error);
          });
        }
        Students.push(student);
      }
      console.log(Students);
    },
    error:function(err){
      console.log(err.message);
    }
  });
}
```

And function takeADegree(id):

```
function takeADegree(id){
    var q = new Parse.Query("Degree");
    q.equalTo("objectId",id);
    return q.first();
}
```

In the picture the result of the function: [image: result]

Fields that indicated by the arrows (oceny-degrees) should look like:
    Student 0 = oceny: Array[3],
    Student 1 = oceny: Array[0],
    Student 2 = oceny: Array[4].
Where is the problem now?